# Usage of Comparative adjectives

Tags: meaning, word-choice, expressions, british-english, comparatives

I find myself using *Comparative adjectives* a lot more than just adjectives is there a rule of thumb?   Here is an example...As I understand it, comparatives compare with something.

> 1. It was not busy tonight at the club? Can you say next week will be busier?
> 2. It was not busy tonight at the club? Can you say next week will be busy?

Now I know both sentences are correct. But what used the most there is a rule of thumb.

Comment: There might be, if we could tell what you mean by "comparative adjectives" and how they differ from "just adjectives". People call things whatever they like, so we need **examples** and not descriptions.

Comment: Here is an example...As I understand it, comparatives compare with something.  Both sentences are correct but what is used the most is there a rule of thumb.

       1. It was not busy tonight at the club? can you say next week will be busier?
       2. It was not busy tonight at the club? can you say next week will be busy?

Comment: If I said to my partner that tonight was not busy, and he responded either way -- "Next week should be busy" or "Next week should be busier" -- it would sound natural to me. I don't know which form is more common. I guess, thought, that the meaning is slightly different. If there were 10 customers this week and my partner predicts 20 for next week, that's obviously busier, while perhaps still not very busy.

Comment: Oh ok thank you!